# Java - Image BMP header

Tags: java, arrays, image, image-processing, bmp

I have a little problem here if someone could help me I will be really glad.
I'm trying to make the next operations

1. Read an BMP image
2. Convert the image into a byte[]
3. Rotate the image with 90 degree(the byte array)
4. And write a new image in some folder

My problem is... In the moment when I'm trying to write the new image I have some problem with BMP header and I don't know why. Please give me some advice if anyone know the answear.

**Convert the image into byte[]**

```
private static byte[] convertAnImageToPixelsArray(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    try {
        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1; ) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConvertImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

**Rotate**

```
private static byte[] rotate(double angle, byte[] pixels, int width, int height) {
    final double radians = Math.toRadians(angle), cos = Math.cos(radians), sin = Math.sin(radians);
    final byte[] pixels2 = new byte[pixels.length];
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            final int
                    centerx = width / 2,
                    centery = height / 2,
                    m = x - centerx,
                    n = y - centery,
                    j = ((int) (m * cos + n * sin)) + centerx,
                    k = ((int) (n * cos - m * sin)) + centery;
            if (j >= 0 && j < width && k >= 0 && k < height)
                pixels2[(y * width + x)] = pixels[(k * width + j)];
        }
    }
    arraycopy(pixels2, 0, pixels, 0, pixels.length);
    return pixels2;
}
```

**Convert the byte[] into image**

```
private static void convertArrayPixelsIntoImage(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    Iterator<?> readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("bmp");

    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();
    Object source = bis;
    ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source);
    reader.setInput(iis, true);
    ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();

    Image image = reader.read(0, param);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(image, null, null);

    File imageFile = new File("Images/Output.bmp");
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "bmp", imageFile);
}
```

**Main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("Images/Input-1.bmp");
    Image img = ImageIO.read(file);
    convertArrayPixelsIntoImage(rotate(90,convertAnImageToPixelsArray(file),img.getWidth(null),img.getHeight(null)));
}
```

***Here it's the error message:***

> Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Unable to read the image header.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you calling these methods? Please show the method that you call them from.

Comment: I've add and the main function now.

Comment: You're rotating the entire image file's contents, including the header, so you're corrupting the header. But why bother reading it twice? You read the image with `ImageIO.read`, and with `convertAnImageToPixelsArray` - that's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not taking into account the structure of the BMP file when you are rotating the image.

You're just reading a `byte[]` from the file, as you could from any file - it's just a stream of bytes.

But in your `rotate` method, you're assuming that the pixel values are:

- 1 byte per pixel;
- Starting at the start of the array.

This isn't the case. Aside from the fact that each pixel will almost certainly be encoded by multiple bytes, the [BMP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) starts with a header, and other metadata.

Whilst you obviously could work out how to decode the data correctly, I would strongly discourage it. You're already reading the image using ImageIO (`Image img = ImageIO.read(file);`), so you've got no need to reinvent the wheel: just use Java's existing image manipulation functionality.

Comment: The problem is... I need to reinvet the wheel because I need some speed. In a normal case I could you **BufferedImage** to rotate this image but this method is to slow... I need something faster, you have any idea?

Comment: You need to understand the BMP file format, understand its structure, and adjust your code to handle it correctly. But you will almost certainly do it wrong, miss edge cases, do it inefficiently etc, and so end up wasting a bunch of time on this. Find an existing implementation.

Comment: just to extend in "each pixel will almost certainly be encoded by multiple bytes" the smallest color information that can be encoded in a Bitmap is 1bit per pixel, these are called monochrome bitmaps, typically they come in a black-white color format, then we have the 1byte per pixel which are called the 8 bit greys, which are images with gray scale color format, with black at the most left, grey at the middle and white at most right,  so indeed there are out there bitmaps which have a 1 byte per pixel.  reference: https://paulbourke.net/dataformats/bitmaps/

Answer (score 1):

You missed that the BMP image has a header like any other format. When you try to rotate the image, you are changing the bytes sequance, so the header loses in other place instead, of beginning. Try to extract first 54 bytes to another array, rotate others and then write to file header at first and ather bytes at second